# SQL Query Dynamically get columns depending on mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am stuck on an issue. I am trying to create a select which returns information depending on the Rules Mapping table. The Rules table tells us where (TableName.ColumnName) value should come from. I have simplified the problem by just creating table variables to find a solution.

I have 3 tables set up.

1. @TableA which contains the Main_ID. First Table.
2. @TableB which contains more information for the Main_ID. Second table.
3. @Rules is the mapping table. It has headers for what the final select should have and also tells us where the the data should come from (What table and column).

[image]

The final expected result I am trying to achieve is this with the above rules is:

[image]

As you can see, I will have 3 columns in total with 3 rows (as I have 3 Main_ID). Data differs depending on the @Rules table. For example, Header C for Main_ID 3 is showing "Address C" as the rule mapping for Header C Main_ID 3 was "@TableB.Address" which means get the information from table @TableB and column Address.

Here is my code for the table set up:

```
DECLARE @TableA AS TABLE
(
    Main_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TableA
VALUES ('Name A'), ('Name B'), ('Name C')

DECLARE @TableB AS TABLE
(
    Secondary_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
    Main_ID INT ,
    Address VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TableB
VALUES (1, 'Address A'), (2, 'Address B'), (3, 'Address C')

DECLARE @Rules AS TABLE
(
    Rule_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
    Main_ID INT ,
    Header_Name VARCHAR(100) ,
    Obtain_From VARCHAR(100) 
)

INSERT INTO @Rules
VALUES 
-- Main_ID 1 AND 2 set up same but third one wants data from a different place.
(1, 'Header A', '@TableA.Main_ID'), (1, 'Header B', '@TableB.Address'), (1, 'Header C', '@TableA.Name'),
(2, 'Header A', '@TableA.Main_ID'), (2, 'Header B', '@TableB.Address'), (2, 'Header C', '@TableA.Name'),
(3, 'Header A', '@TableA.Main_ID'), (3, 'Header B', '@TableA.Name'), (3, 'Header C', '@TableB.Address')

SELECT * FROM @TableA
SELECT * FROM @TableB
SELECT * FROM @Rules

/*
    Final result set should be:
    Header A        Header B        Header C
    1               Address A       Name A
    2               Address B       Name B
    3               Name C          Address C       
*/
```

What I have tried so far is joining the table together but there are too many rows.

[image]
[image]

Any ideas how I can achieve the final expected result?

Comment: @nbk I will explore how to do it via SQL Dynamic. Although I am not sure how the select would look like.

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors - use formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a two way to do it.

The first way is static and easy.
You can use CASE expression for your mapping like that:

```
SELECT
    [Header A]  = CASE r_headera.Obtain_From WHEN '@TableA.Main_ID' THEN CAST(a.Main_ID AS NVARCHAR(100)) WHEN '@TableA.Name' THEN CAST(a.Name AS NVARCHAR(100)) WHEN '@TableB.Address' THEN CAST(b.Address AS NVARCHAR(100)) END,
    [Header B]  = CASE r_headerb.Obtain_From WHEN '@TableA.Main_ID' THEN CAST(a.Main_ID AS NVARCHAR(100)) WHEN '@TableA.Name' THEN CAST(a.Name AS NVARCHAR(100)) WHEN '@TableB.Address' THEN CAST(b.Address AS NVARCHAR(100)) END,
    [Header C]  = CASE r_headerc.Obtain_From WHEN '@TableA.Main_ID' THEN CAST(a.Main_ID AS NVARCHAR(100)) WHEN '@TableA.Name' THEN CAST(a.Name AS NVARCHAR(100)) WHEN '@TableB.Address' THEN CAST(b.Address AS NVARCHAR(100)) END
FROM
    @TableA AS a
    LEFT JOIN @TableB AS b ON b.Main_ID = a.Main_ID
    LEFT JOIN @Rules AS r_headera ON r_headera.Main_ID = a.Main_ID AND r_headera.Header_Name = 'Header A'
    LEFT JOIN @Rules AS r_headerb ON r_headerb.Main_ID = a.Main_ID AND r_headerb.Header_Name = 'Header B'
    LEFT JOIN @Rules AS r_headerc ON r_headerc.Main_ID = a.Main_ID AND r_headerc.Header_Name = 'Header C'
```

Otherwise, you can use other structs such as [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16), [OUTER APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) etc.

The result:

| Header A | Header B | Header C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Address A | Name A |
| 2 | Address B | Name B |
| 3 | Name C | Address C |

And the second way is Dynamic SQL with [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-dynamic-sql) .
If you need help with that, I can prepare an example for you.

Comment: Thanks. That works out for me. I have a good idea how to get it via SQL Dynamic now after looking at your example.

Comment: You're welcome, if there is any issue about that I'm here to help.